QGIS - Feature total shown but no features in attribute table
wells is a geopackage, opened it this morning and the attribute table is empty.
Anything I've done wrong or is the file somehow corrupted?
Is there any way to go back to previous saves of a geopackage or qgz project file?

Where does the data come from? Did it work properly before? If so, what changed?

I created the wells layer and added all of the data, it worked properly on Friday. Nothing changed that I know of.

Have you tried adding the layer to a new QGIS project? Another thing you can try is fix geometries

Tried both of those.
